# Replace LinkedList element value through LinkedList.Enumerator

Tags: c#, java

I realize there are no way for me to replace value through `LinkedList.Enumerator`.

For instance, I try to port the below Java code to C#:

**Java code:**

```
ListIterator<Double> itr1 = linkedList1.listIterator();
ListIterator<Double> itr2 = linkedList2.listIterator();
while(itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext()){
    Double d = itr1.next() + itr2.next();
    itr1.set(d);
}
```

**C# code:**

```
LinkedList<Double>.Enumerator itr1 = linkedList1.GetEnumerator();            
LinkedList<Double>.Enumerator itr2 = linkedList2.GetEnumerator();

 while(itr1.MoveNext() && itr2.MoveNext()){                
    Double d = itr1.Current + itr2.Current;
    // Opps. Compilation error!
    itr1.Current = d;
}
```

Any other techniques I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#'s `LinkedList` enumerator enumerates the *values*, not the *nodes*.

If you want to modify nodes as in the Java version, I think you have to "enumerate" the nodes manually:

```
LinkedListNode<Double> nod1 = linkedList1.First;
LinkedListNode<Double> nod2 = linkedList2.First;
while (nod1 != null && nod2 != null)
{
    Double d = nod1.Value + nod2.Value;              
    nod1.Value = d;
    nod1 = nod1.Next;
    nod2 = nod2.Next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's sufficient to simply build a new list:

```
linkedList1 = new LinkedList<double> (linkedList1.Zip(linkedList2, (first, second) => first + second));
```

If you need the original list to be changed, you might want to do

```
 var tmp = linkedList1.Zip(linkedList2, (first, second) => first + second).ToList ();
 linkedList1.Clear ();
 linkedList1.AddRange (tmp);
```

Comment: `linkedList1` is a `LinkedList<double>` so you can't use `.ToList();` You need something like: `linkedList1 = new LinkedList<double>(linkedList1.Zip(linkedList2, (first, second) => first + second));`

Comment: Why shouldn't I be able to use `ToList ()` for a `List<double>`???? I just tried it, and I do not see any problem. It does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Because it's not a `List<>`, it's a [`LinkedList<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)